# Running multiple ASP.NET Core 2.2 webapps side-by-side in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

I'm trying to run 2 ASP.NET Core 2.2 webapps side-by-side on IIS 10. I created CoreTestApp1 & CoreTestApp2 (default VS template, no added code), i.e. both set up for In-Process hosting.

After I restart my server (IIS Mgr), the first webapp that I open in a browser (e.g. CoreTestApp1) runs fine; if I open the second one (CoreTestApp2) I get an error "HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure".

If I restart my server again and open CoreTestApp2 first, then that runs fine, but now CoreTestApp1 causes the same error.

I tried running 2 ASP.NET Framework apps side by side, and that works fine.

Judging by the info I found (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index), it seems I should be able to run multiple core apps side-by-side?

Is there some extra config stuff that I'm missing?

Not sure if this is relevant, but I used Visual Studio's publish (to folder) with these settings...

- Configuration = Debug
- Target Framework = netcoreapp2.2
- Deployment mode = framework-dependent
- Target runtime = portable

Comment: Are they in different application pools?

Comment: Thx for pointing me in the right direction, Lex :-)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Lex's suggestion and some more googling, I found the answer to my question [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22):

> The ASP.NET Core module V2 running in InProcess mode has to run in its own dedicated Application Pool. According to the documentation you cannot run multiple sites or virtual directories (Web Applications) using the the ASP.NET Core Module in a single Application Pool. Make sure each ASP.NET Core app on IIS gets its own Application Pool.

Creating extra Application Pools and assigning each ASP.NET Core app its own solved my problem; instructions on how to create App Pools [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/#setup).